Direct users to specific locations
Does anyone know how to recommend a tutorial or material that explains how to use the Arcore with the geolocation creator, not just to show reference points, but to indicate the path to be followed by the user, presenting a route on the screen by determining 2 points (departure and arrival). For now I use Arcore in Unity to position points of interest, but I would like to be more daring by including this functionality. Can anybody help me?
I represent control points in AR using the geospatial creator, but I cannot indicate a route between one and the other. For example, I am at point A and I want to go to point C, without going through B, can this route be calculated, like on a map and presented in AR? How to do this?

Does anyone know how to help??
